# Keypress Simulation in Games [C++]

Tags: c++, events, input

So I have a working keypress simulator. It presses the key "W" every 2 seconds. I'm testing it out on a game that uses the keys 'WASD' however, when I run the program and run up my game, it doesn't move my character? I have to physically push the W key to move it. Any ideas why?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>

class KeyBot {
    private:
        INPUT _buffer[1];

    public:
        KeyBot();
        void KeyUp(char key);
        void KeyDown(char key);
        void KeyClick(char key);
};

KeyBot::KeyBot() {
    _buffer->type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    _buffer->ki.wScan = 0;
    _buffer->ki.time = 0;
    _buffer->ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
}

void KeyBot::KeyUp(char key) {
    _buffer->ki.wVk = key;
    _buffer->ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, _buffer, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void KeyBot::KeyDown(char key) {
    _buffer->ki.wVk = key;
    _buffer->ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, _buffer, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void KeyBot::KeyClick(char key) {
    KeyDown(key);
    Sleep(10);
    KeyUp(key);
}

int main() {
    KeyBot bot;

    while (1) {

    bot.KeyDown(0x57); //Press and hold 'W'
    Sleep(2000); // Wait 2000 ms (2 seconds)
    bot.KeyUp(0x37);
    }
}
```

Comment: We probably need to see the code that actually handles the input for you …

Comment: @AurelBílý What do you mean? This is the only code that I have.

Comment: @AurelBílý Would I have to send that input into the game in order for it to work? Sorry, pretty new to programming.

Comment: Is the key that your bot is releasing supposed to be different from the one it's pressing?

Comment: @zyndor Nope. I just want it to move my character forward every 2 seconds. So it goes like this, (move forward) -> *waits two seconds* -> (move forward) -> *waits two seconds* -> and so on. :P

Comment: @zyndor If you run my code and open up notepad, you can see that it is clearly inputting the "W" however, if you run a game that uses the controls 'WASD' and sit there, your character just won't move. :/

Comment: Then, it's what @AurelBílý has already said - can we see the input handling code?

Comment: @zyndor What do you mean by `input handling code`? Sorry if I don't quite understand. Isn't the main method doing all the work?

Comment: I assume the game you're testing this on is not your own, then?

Comment: @AurelBílý Nope. It's called Counter-Strike: Source. I just wanted to do some basic movements using C++. But, do you know why the input isn't being sent to the game? Just curious.

Comment: The game you want to control with KeyBot is a separate application that has its own event handling implemented in some way, like any other application (i.e. Notepad) does.

For whatever reason it seems to not pick up the events generated by SendInput. I'm quite intrigued to test it with my game code, but I'm at work, where I don't have the same setup, so bear with me for a few hours.

Comment: @zyndor Okay. thanks for trying to help me! :D

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29cf2de9-412e-44dd-9050-174089d8e2a2/sendkeys-and-directx?forum=netfxbcl) describes a similar problem - DirectX input handling seem to ignore normal scancodes; try using their DIK_ variant, from the dinput.h DirectX header.